# Use Google Closure Compiler as a library instead of a script

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-compiler

Is it possible for me to write my own Java Main Class that calls methods in compiler.jar.

I would like to make multiple calls to the compiler and do not want to write code to use Runtime.exec and also do not want to have to wait for Java to load up before every call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is fully supported.

Overview: http://blog.bolinfest.com/2009/11/calling-closure-compiler-from-java.html
Reference: http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html

Answer (score 2):

It looks like javadoc documentation is no longer available online. In order to create your local copy of documentation:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/google/closure-compiler.git
$ cd closure-compiler
$ ant javadoc
```

The documentation will be created in the `build/javadoc` folder.

Note that [ANT](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler) is required to run the last command.